# "Was" or "Were" (Subjunctive mood)

Tags: grammar, idiomatic-language

In a story I'm writing a bad guy says this:

*I would probably kill myself if I was/were disabled like you.*

Elsewhere in the story I write this:

He smiles as if it was/were a compliment.

Questions:

1. Is it optional in both sentences whether to use "was" or "were"? Will anyone find it grammatically wrong if I used "was" in both sentences?
2. In the first sentence would it be more natural to say "I would probably have killed myself..."? And if so, should it be "...if I was disabled like you." or "...if I had been disabled like you."?

Thank you.

Comment: We don't generally give writing advice on this site. Having said that - let your choice fit your character. You can mix **was** and **were** according to character and narrator as long as you are consistent. As to your second question, again use your character's background as a guide.